# How to show message when Ajax function returns 0 record

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Trying to show a message "No data to display" (while using a `DataTable`) when `JSON` returns 0 in a `Ajax` call. But can't figure it out how.

Tried

```
$("#noData").show();
```

with a *if* statement but didn't work.

```
<div id="noData" class="grid_4 alpha" style="display: none;">No data to display</div>
```

Here is the code that plots the table.

```
function FillTable() {
    var title = plotData.title + ' / ' + YMLabel(plotData.startYM) + " - " + YMLabel(plotData.endYM);

    if (table != null) {
        table.fnDestroy(true);
    }

    $("#tabContainer").empty()
        .html('<h1 class="pageTitle">' + title + '</h1><img src="../styles/loading.gif">');

    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax_incidents_table.asp",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            startYM: plotData.startYM,
            endYM: plotData.endYM
        },
        timeout: 10000,
        success: function (ajaxData) {
            var htmlstr = '<h1 class="pageTitle">' + title + '</h1><table id="table"></table>';
            $('#tabContainer').html(htmlstr);
            var tabSettings = {
                sDom: 'rt',
                bPaginate: false,
                sScrollX: "100%",
                bScrollCollapse: true,
                bFilter: false,
                aoColumns: ajaxData.aoColumns,
                aaData: ajaxData.aaData
            }
            table = $('#table').dataTable(tabSettings);
            SetTooltips()
            ShowDescription();
        },
        error: function (x, t, m) {
            alert('error: ' + m);
            $('#tabContainter').html("<h3>An error has occured. (" + t + " / " + m + ")</h3>");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I removed a couple tags that didn't seem relevant. Feel free to re-add them if I was wrong.

Comment: It will be difficult to answer this question without seeing the structure of `ajaxData`, but I assume you could check the length of `ajaxData.aaData`. What is the if statement you tried that didn't work?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LFuQc/
here is the ajaxData `structure`.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't really help me. I need to see the generated json, not the vb source.

Comment: I tried to print generated JSON through
DebugWrite("jsonData:" & json)

but that does not get printed because SQL Query return 0 record.

Answer (score 0):

0 would be returned only if the request comes back with a 200 (success). Otherwise, the `error` function would execute and would prompt the user about the error.

So you can try this out:

```
success: function (data) {
  if(data == 0) { // if the result is 0
    $('#noData').show(); // show the div..
  }
}
```

This way, you can check for the value of the result in a success function.

Secondly, you can try to check for the Network requests in the Browser's Inspector's Network tab. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> and then go to Network tab, and check for all the information related to the request, afterwards code it out depending on the conditions.

Comment: This is what I tried before and no message was displayed. data is 0 I know because I try to print out the 
    DebugWrite("No data to display")
when record = 0 on the server side.

Comment: Are you sure the only return is as: `return 0;` ?? If no, then this won't work. As the result must be only single charactered 0 ...

Comment: I guess I am doing it wrong on the server-side code. When I get SQL returns 0 records then I stop running the code there. As you can check it http://jsfiddle.net/LFuQc/ 
line 45 to 51. I guess here JSON is not even getting created and passed. Sorry very little knowledge in this.

Comment: Exactly, try adding this one line at the end: `return 0;` then the result would be just a single character 0 :)

Comment: Where `return 0;` can be added? If you could specify the line number from the fiddle would be really helpful.

Comment: It cannot be done in the fiddle brother. It would be written at the end of the code at the server-side...

Answer (score 0):

Client side code definitely needed what @Afzaal Ahmed Zeeshan has answered above.

```
if(ajaxData.aaData == null) 
{ 
   $('#noData').show();
}
```

Along with that the actual problem was on the `Ajax` part. The following needed to be passed when database query returned zero record.

```
json=json&",""aaData"":[null]}"
```

Client side code was expecting json-formatted data. But I was trying to display the message for NO DATA using `Response.Write` which sends a text (string) to the main-asp file and that is not `Jason` formatted.